# WPF Adding UserControl to RadRibbonTab

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm learning to use WPF. 
I'm trying to make RadRibonTab in one file and it's content in the other, however i'm unable to do that.

My parent UserControl:

`<UserControl x:Class="TelerikTotorial2.RibbonBar.RibonBarView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:historyTab="clr-namespace:TelerikTotorial2.RibbonBar.History"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             >
    <telerik:RadRichTextBoxRibbonUI ApplicationButtonContent="File"  CollapseThresholdSize="50,50" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,-0.2">
        <telerik:RadRibbonTab Header="History" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0" Width="107.2">
            <historyTab:HistoryTabView/>
        </telerik:RadRibbonTab>
    </telerik:RadRichTextBoxRibbonUI>
</UserControl>`

UserControl which I try to add

```
<UserControl x:Class="TelerikTotorial2.RibbonBar.History.HistoryTabView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:history="clr-namespace:TelerikTotorial2.RibbonBar.History"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

<telerik:RadRibbonGroup Header="Tools">
    <telerik:RadRibbonButton Text="View" Size="Large"/>
</telerik:RadRibbonGroup></UserControl>
```

However I get exception "InvalidOperationException: Specified element is already the logical child of another element.".
If i replace `<historyTab:HistoryTabView/>` with

`<telerik:RadRibbonGroup Header="Tools">
        <telerik:RadRibbonButton Text="View" Size="Large"/>
    </telerik:RadRibbonGroup>`

then everything is working, however I want to have this code in separate files. Perhaps someone can explain what I am doing wrong? Perhaps it isn't possible  to add UserControl to other UserControl?